# Uncountable open square

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my homework I am trying to show that the open square $(0,2)\times(0,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is uncountable.

I have used the diagonal proof to show that $(0,2)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is an uncountable interval. But I don't know how to transfer this to the open square.

Any help/tip would appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(0,2)$ is uncountable, $(0,2)\times\{1\}$ is uncountable too. But $(0,2)\times\{1\}$ is a subset of $(0,2)\times(0,2)$. Therefore, $(0,2)\times(0,2)$ is uncountable.